# Are files tagged in MacOS Finder locatable by tag in iOS

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, icloud, finder-tag

I only today started tagging files in MacOS Finder.
I was pleased to confirm that I could locate those files in Finder by searching for the tag.

My iPhone and my MacBook are both logged into iCloud using the same account.

However, even after restarting my phone, and forcing a Photos sync, I am unable to locate those files in my phone by searching for the tag.

Are there other steps I need to take before the file tags are synced with iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

I am able to see tags sync only for files I store in iCloud Drive on the Mac and that sync to iPadOS and iOS. The rest of the files are invisible and not searchable from iOS.

Tagging a file from iOS I see it in about 10 seconds tagged on the Mac and when I remove that tag on the Mac, it’s not live refreshed, but updates fast there as well when I search again.